# Shutdown Raspberry over ssh

Tags: ssh, putty

to Shutdown my Raspberry I type `sudo shutdown -h -P now` this works fine when I am directly contected via USB Keyboard and Hdmi display but when Iam connected over SHH from my windows Pc using Putty it does not shutdown. 
It looks like this :

```
pi@transceiver02 ~ $ sudo shutdown -h -P now
The system is going down for system halt NOW!s/1) (Fri Sep 11 09:45:06 2015):
pi@transceiver02 ~ $ ls
bluez-5.33           command   python_games    testInst
bluez-5.33.tar.xz    Desktop   ShutdownBtn.py  text.txt
bluez-5.33.tar.xz.1  PTest.py  ShutDownBtn.sh
pi@transceiver02 ~ $
```

So How do I realy shutdown the Raspberry over SSH ?

Comment: Please supply information about what OS and what version of that OS you are using. Also, please tell us, whether you use systemd or not.

Comment: I am using Raspbian Version  3.18 i think i did not uses systemd but i am not sure

Comment: Try `ps ax | grep -E "(systemd|upstart|init)"` in a terminal and look for `systemd` or `init`. This will be your init system.

Comment: OK I get   `1 ?        Ss     0:01 init [2]`

Comment: Thanks Erverbody I use `sudo init 0` and it works!

Answer (score 15):

Depending on your *init system*, the command may vary.

On a Raspbian with systemd you can switch off the system with:

`sudo systemctl poweroff`

On a system with SysV-Init system, you can use:

`sudo shutdown -h now`

or

`sudo halt`

You can, of course, ommit the `sudo` if you are already logged in as root or `su`'d before executing.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo shutdown -h now` should work and I do this all the time. The `-P` doesn't hurt, but as the Pi doesn't have power control does nothing.

This is the recommended method of halting. It can take a little time to actually shut down. It is possible that some running system process may slow things down.

Answer (score 2):

Another datapoint, if its useful.  I regularly shutdown via ssh, but I run ssh from the command line (not via Putty).

The following shuts down my Pi and powers off (HDMI out becomes disabled, but always on Power LED stays on).  Note: this is on Raspbian, and I ran uname to show you my version.  The commands below were run remotely from my Macbook.

```
# ssh pi@raspberrypi -t uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
Connection to raspberrypi closed.
# ssh pi@raspberrypi -t sudo shutdown -h -P now

Broadcast message from root@raspberrypi (pts/0) (Fri Sep 11 12:40:01 2015):
The system is going down for system halt NOW!
Connection to raspberrypi closed.
```